# xtext: basic "wizard" project gives errors on first build

Tags: syntax-highlighting, xtext

I'm using (the rather heavy weight) xtext to create a basic DSL parser and text highlighting.

I'm following the getting started tutorial at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Xtext/GettingStarted

The output in the console i'm getting is:

> 0    [main] INFO  eclipse.emf.mwe.core.WorkflowRunner  - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   0    [main] INFO  eclipse.emf.mwe.core.WorkflowRunner  - EMF Modeling Workflow Engine 0.7.2, Build v200908120417
>   0    [main] INFO  eclipse.emf.mwe.core.WorkflowRunner  - (c) 2005-2009 openarchitectureware.org and contributors
>   0    [main] INFO  eclipse.emf.mwe.core.WorkflowRunner  - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   0    [main] INFO  eclipse.emf.mwe.core.WorkflowRunner  - running workflow: C:/Users/Richard/workspace/org.xtext.example.mydsl.generator/src/workflow/MyDslGenerator.mwe
>   0    [main] INFO  eclipse.emf.mwe.core.WorkflowRunner  - 
>   297  [main] ERROR eclipse.emf.mwe.core.WorkflowRunner  - [ERROR]: Class not found: 'org.xtext.example.MyDslStandaloneSetup'(Element: bean register class='org.xtext.example.MyDslStandaloneSetup' in C:/Users/Richard/workspace/org.xtext.example.mydsl.generator/src/workflow/MyDslGenerator.mwe:11; Reported by: -UNKNOWN-)
>   297  [main] ERROR eclipse.emf.mwe.core.WorkflowRunner  - Workflow interrupted because of configuration errors.

I get this output at step 4 "DSL Generation" in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a simple mestake made by me, while following the tutorial. In short I was running the incorrect .mwe file. The one I was running found in org.xtext.example.mydsl.generator/src/workflow while the .mwe I needed is listed under org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org.xtext.example.